# Uso de "a cuyo" con el verbo "representar"

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

¿Cuál de estas dos frases sería la correcta?

> Un agente es quien se encarga de encontrar editorial para los libros cuyos escritores representa.

O:

> Un agente es quien se encarga de encontrar editorial para los libros a cuyos escritores representa.

No sé por qué en un principio me sonó bien la primera opción, pero blonfu me advirtió sobre el uso de la preposición "a" antes de "cuyos", y realmente así parece más correcto (se dice "representar algo" pero "representar a alguien").

En todo caso me queda la duda: ¿serían válidas las dos opciones, o solo la segunda?

Answer (score 1):

Consultada a la RAE a través de Enclave, su respuesta ha sido la siguiente (negritas mías):

> **En efecto, ambas opciones son válidas.**
>
> El uso de la preposición *a* se justifica porque el sintagma nominal que funciona como complemento directo se refiere a persona, pero también es admisible la omisión de la preposición por la presencia del determinante posesivo *cuyo* y la ausencia de ambigüedad.

Buscando otras consultas de la misma categoría, veo que alguien preguntó si en la siguiente construcción se podía omitir la preposición del complemento directo:

> Los preparadores le enviaron a algunos clientes difíciles para que pusieran a prueba su técnica mercantil.

La respuesta fue:

> Puesto que el referente del complemento directo es animado, se justifica el uso de la preposición *a* (*Los preparadores le enviaron a algunos clientes...*); no obstante, al estar presente un sintagma nominal de persona con un cuantificador (*algunos*), también es posible omitir la preposición (*Los preparadores le enviaron algunos clientes...*).

Comment: En realidad, me parece que estás en lo cierto en cuanto a que "A cuyos  escritores" es la forma más correcta (para mí, la única correcta). El otro ejemplo es diferente, puesto que la regla dice que debe prescindirse de la preposición "a" frente a CDs personales cuando existe un CI también personal ("le" en este caso) a fin de evitar ambigüedad: *Ellos enviaron algunos clientes difíciles **a** él.*